# How much is the new Air Force One projected to cost?

Tags: united-states, politics, economics

President-Elect, Donald Trump [recently tweeted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dDPGR.png) that the cost of replacing Air Force One, the Presidents airliners would be 4 billion US dollars.

This figure is [reported](http://www.dailymail.co.uk/news/article-4015320/Trump-RIGHT-Air-Force-One-Government-budget-documents-Boeing-program-slated-cost-4-billion.html) as [accurate](http://www.hannity.com/articles/election-493995/despite-boeings-claims-trumps-4-billion-15373344/) elsewhere.

Other [news](http://www.business-standard.com/article/international/trump-calls-air-force-one-s-price-tag-out-of-order-boeing-promises-restraints-116120800046_1.html) reports for listed a [fraction](http://thehill.com/homenews/campaign/308990-boeing-says-it-is-under-170-million-contract-to-work-on-air-force-one) of that as the [current](http://www.cnbc.com/2016/12/06/trumps-air-force-one-tweet-was-a-brilliant-move-commentary.html) contract, [170 million dollars](http://www.huffingtonpost.com/dorian-de-wind/air-force-one-deserves-more_b_13539376.html).

Will replacing Air Force One cost 4 billion US dollars?

Comment: The $170M contract is for designing, not building, the next Air Force One. The actual costs are forecasted to be about $2.9 billion, although it's not uncommon for these to come in over budget. All this is explained by the articles you linked to - what's your question, exactly?

Comment: @ff524 The articles I've linked to say $1.69B, $2.9B & $3B. No one has said as high as $4B except Donny. My question is will it cost that much and how did he arrive at that number?

Comment: Is there a chance that different #s are due to in/excluding maintenance costs or other differences in accounting? There's a lot of ways to define what a project like that "costs"

Comment: @ff524 The $170 M is just for requirements discovery and preliminary design work, not even close to all of the design work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Independent confirmation of cost from non-Trump source:

Your link in second paragraph has independent confirmation from NBC news (not exactly a hotbed of Trump support) twitter citing Air Force:

> NBC Nightly News ✔ @NBCNightlyNews
>   US Air Force official: **Price of new Air Force One project expected to be more than $4B by time aircraft delivered** - @ckubeNBC

---

---

## As to where the number comes from:

1. That link also shows the [military form for "PE 0401319F: Presidential Aircraft Replacement (PAR)"](http://www.dtic.mil/descriptivesum/Y2017/AirForce/stamped/U_0401319F_5_PB_2017.pdf)

   The total cost in the form (2015 through 2021) is 11.006+82.420+351.220+625.631+740.999+573.711+487.270 = **$2.9B**

   That number ONLY includes R&D ("3600: Research, Development, Test & Evaluation, Air Force / BA 5: System") and **does NOT include procurement**
2. Same Hannity article quotes procurement costs at ~1B, but the source is just a tweet from unknown guy.

   However, this seems the right ballpark. A comment from @Mark states

   > [Boeing's list price for the 747-800 is around $400M for an unmodified airliner](http://www.boeing.com/company/about-bca/index.page%23/prices#/prices), and the Air Force is planning on buying two of them.

## If you take ~$1B procurement at face value, that's where you arrive at $2.9B+$1B=$3.9B, almost Trump's $4B

Comment: $1 billion for procurement is reasonable.  [Boeing's list price for the 747-800](http://www.boeing.com/company/about-bca/index.page%23/prices#/prices) is around $400M for an unmodified airliner, and the Air Force is planning on buying two of them.

Comment: For what it's worth, [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boeing_VC-25) suggests that the procurement unit cost for the current VC-25's was $325 M and that was in the late 1980s. However, in a quick search, I didn't see a definitive source to back that up.